# How to set logging level in Flask?

Tags: python, logging, flask, uwsgi

I've just setup an [nginx](http://nginx.org) server with [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org) to serve my website which I built in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org). I now want to setup logging, which I've done like this:

```
logfileHandler = RotatingFileHandler('/var/log/trs/debug.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)
logfileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app.logger.addHandler(logfileHandler)
```

And I then log some things using the following:

```
current_app.logger.debug('DEBUG LOG')
current_app.logger.info('INFO LOG')
current_app.logger.warning('WARNING LOG')
current_app.logger.error('ERROR LOG')
current_app.logger.critical('CRITICAL LOG')
```

To my surprise however, I only see the last three logs in the `debug.log`:

```
WARNING LOG
ERROR LOG
CRITICAL LOG
```

Any idea why debug and info are not displaying? All tips are welcome!

Comment: have you tried `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` at the top-level, before you create any flask bits?

Comment: if all fails, set log level directly on `logging.root` in addition to your handler

Comment: @qarma - That fixed it, thanks! If you add your comment as an answer I can select your answer.